# Use of a Compiler from Java to Machine Code

Tags: java, c, assembly, compilation, jvm

Why is java code not compiled to machine code by many people even if it will run faster than the JVM and without the JVM?

I am a computer science student at the TUM germany.
I know the benefits and disadvantages of java and the pros/cons of e.g. C/C++.

The java syntax is very similar to C++ (cannot speak about C, have not looked at it ever). 
In java you dont use the stack explicitly. Compiling java code (after fixing the minor syntax differences) with a C compiler will only use the heap then.
Also created objects on the heap will not be freed automatically.

I recently had to code a "compiler" for java syntax so I do have a basic understanding of parsing code and tranforming it into usable assembler code.

If a company created an efficient parser that finds the lifetime of objects in java code to change these objects to use the stack in C++ instead, a compiler could compile this code the same way as regular C++ which could result in a better performance than using the JVM. Also heap objects will get freed after not being used anymore. (Even if you had to manually add the lines where objects should be freed, I dont think this might be hard)

I know I broke this huge topic down to this small explanation. Is there anything I am missing or is there something wrong with my thoughts?

(I am "in danger of being blocked from asking any more". Please help me to change my topic to better suit this forum!)

EDIT:
I am using both, java at university, C++ for doing projects at home. For me the differences are minor and can be changed easily. That is my experience at least.

Comment: "_after fixing the minor syntax differences_" - that is a much, much harder task than you seem to think. Java and C++ have some minor syntax similarities, but it stops there. They are completely different languages.

Comment: _"even if it will run faster than the JVM"_ - how do you justify that assumption?

Comment: _how do you justify that assumption?_ Code specifically compiled and optimized for a cpu architecture with a specific ISA will in most cases run faster than the JVM itself thats one main disadvantage of java and its VM

Comment: And you also take into account things like JIT compilation and potential long-term optimization steps that can only be executed _because_ the code is running within the JVM? Anyway (i.e. assuming C code indeed runs faster), the answer to your question is most likely: Because it's not worth the hassle and you usually lose a lot more performance due to (your own) bad implementation than due to the JVM.

Comment: I do not know much about JIT, but is JIT not about making a scripting language faster so it is "more close" to the performance of a a head of time compiled program? And yes, most of the performance is lost by the programmer himself, I totaly agree. Still: An optimized java program will "lose" in performance results against an optimized C++ program (of course there can be a lot more optimized in C++ over java). When talking about such a compiler I am not thinking of a company tool but rather of an open compiler usable for every java programmer.

Answer (score 0):

*efficient parser that finds the lifetime of objects* : this is impossible to do, the lifetime cannot be determined statistically except on special/simple cases.

*Even if you had to manually add the lines where objects should be freed, I dont think this might be hard* : this is what we do in C or C++, the *mark* being a call to free/delete :-)

This is not for nothing garbage collectors exists, and you cannot replace easily a garbage collector by magic.

When there is no garbage collector there are some ways to help to free the allocated memory automatically, for instance to use `std::shared_ptr`, `std::string` also use an internal counter to know when the internal `char *` can be freed. The use of a counter of references is simple, but the count of references have to not overflow the counter, and that way does not work when you have a circle because the counters cannot go down to 0, again there is no magic

Comment: _this is impossible to do_: I do not know. That is an assumption by me. If you think about it: Objects local to methods can be directly changed to use the stack. Of course there are far more complicated scenarios. Thats why I added _"Even if you had to manually add the lines where objects should be freed, I dont think this might be hard"_ I know thats exactly what is done in C/C++ and it is not difficult. A simple idea: Adding a simple keyword to mark where an object is not used anymore (even explicitly call _foo = null_.

Comment: Pointers are actually an option but this will increase the memory usage which is "bad" in many scenarios.

Comment: @MarcoZielbauer: “*Objects local to methods can be directly changed to use the stack*”. That’s possible, but what do you gain from that? The stack resides in the same RAM chips as the heap memory, so there is no performance difference. A C++ compiler places objects on the stack if the programmers tells it to do it, mainly because the programmer told it to do so. But since C++ objects on the heap require an explicit `delete` operation, they are truly more expensive than stack objects. But in Java, objects do not require a `delete` operation, hence, are not subject to this issue.

Comment: When compiling it to assembler code it will have an impact. As you said heap objects _are truly more expensive than stack objects_. In java it doesnt make a difference yes. But the GC has to care about these objects -> garbage collection times increase.

Comment: @MarcoZielbauer that’s not how a garbage collector works. The cost of garbage collection depends on the number of object which are still alive, as those are the objects which have to be processed. The costs for deallocation are exactly zero as deallocation simply doesn’t happen. Of course, when you try to transform the code to something without a garbage collector, you are introducing costs which you can mitigate by identifying purely local objects, but you are solving a problem you’ve just introduced, so there’s still no advantage in doing the transformation.